# Telegram bot doesn't answer after CommandHandler starts

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, pypi, python-telegram-bot

So, I'm kinda new creating bots with Python. I'm using PyPI(PY Telegram Bot). I've been learning a lot during these days and it even started working. While using MessageHandler I could pretty much send a message and the bot would return me a text or a picture.

But now I want something different. I want to start creating a game for Telegram, still to learn more on how to use the library.

The thing is: eveytime I want the bot to answer me, it doesn't work. Basically when entering the rockpaperscissors function, I want it to show a text asking for an option, then, whatever this answer is leads me to an answer by the bot. But whenever I answer, the bot never answers back.

[Just an example of what happens:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEkHe.png)

And here is the source code. I excluded the superfluous sections so it wouldn't be that messy. Any help is appreciated :)

```
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters, ConversationHandler, CallbackContext
import random

def rockpaperscissors(update, context):
    update.message.reply_text('Rock, paper, scissors. Return an option')
    msgUsr = str(update.message.text)
    if msgUser == "rock":
        update.message.reply_text("You chose 'rock'")

def main():
    token ='(token)'
    updater = Updater(token=token, use_context=True)
    dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('rps',rockpaperscissors))
    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your bot is expecting a command `/rps`, and responding correctly. However, when you send a plain message (rather than a command), the bot just doesn't know what to do. Note that the function `rockpaperscissors` is only called when the user sends a message starting with `/rps`  or `/rps@yourbot` , but it never equals to "rock". So your `if` will never be executed.

You must add a [`MessageHandler`](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.ext.messagehandler.html) and associate another function to, well, handle the message.